# Running hadoop as a linux service

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am neither an expert to linux not to hadoop but I followed the instruction for installation hadoop in distributed mode(Hortonworks distribution and manual) and when I got to section starting the cluster I give a thought why this couldn't be run as a service.

Does anybody have some experience with running hadoop as a linux service? Is it a good or bad idea? Pros and cons? Any hints doing that?

Any help will be appriciated. 
Thx

Comment: I have not used Hortonworks distribution. But Cloudera Hadoop has set the related scripts to a daemon service. So when you start the computer, hadoop will automatically start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run hadoop as service for that you will need to write small script that can setup environment and start appropriate deamon such as `datanode` and `nodemanager` on `slave` and `namenode` on hdfs server and `resourcemanager` on `yarn server` etc, then save script into /etc/init.d/, then you need specify create link appropriately in rcX.d for more [update-rc.d](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/update-rc.d/)